# Detect touch device pinch-level (zoom)

Tags: javascript, touch

Is it possbile to detect the pinch (zoom) level for touch-devices, assuming the default level equals '1' ? The reason is that I want page-element(s) disabled (display:none) depending on the pinch level.

It would be nice if it is possible to have it in a single function that sets the zoom level value, something like:

```
var ZOOM = 1;
function detectPinchZoomLevel(ev){
  /*
      //some calculations here...
      ZOOM = 1.235 ; (for example)
  */
}
document.addEventListener('touchmove',detectPinchZoomLevel}, false);
```

thanks for help

Comment: You might need to check this out first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers#5078596

Comment: thank you, that link helped alot. The answer is using the visualViewport. I'll add a short answer for it

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly simple actually:

```
var ZOOM = 1;
var viewport = window.visualViewport;
function resizeHandler() {ZOOM = viewport.scale;}   
window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
```